# In firefox for android browser, my css background color doesn't stop, making the page unnecessarily long

Tags: css, firefox

When I view the site I'm working on using firefox for android, it looks OK if the site is viewed landscape.

However, when the site is viewed portrait, the color defined in body {background: #185fa0;} continues on, making the page unnecessarily long. The image is an example, I would like the blue background to finish much closer to the content, like it does in every other browser. Can anyone advise?

My CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #252525;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background: #185FA0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

An example: [image]

Thank-you!

**UPDATE:**

I  found this earlier today, suggesting that it is a bug with firefox, but I don't know how to fix it. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1045459

Comment: the problem doesn't really seem to relevant to your code above.

Comment: @sdcr Thanks, I don't have a clue what's causing it, so I have updated my question with all the css code I'm using.

Comment: it very hard to investigate, i would suggest to look into the media queries first.

Comment: @sdcr I deleted all of the media queries and the problem still exists!

Comment: @sdcr I found this earlier today, but I don't know how to fix it https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1045459 . Suggesting it is a firefox bug

Comment: if you believe it's a bug, then there is nothing we can do really, but if you think there might be a workaround, please create a simple demo.